# Using python, skip errors and continue scripts or insert a fix

Tags: python, exception, error-handling

I am currently using a python script for specific books purchased that need to be read on a device that is not compatible with a given format.
The python script is obok.py and located here: http://pastebin.com/1jUzW8qx
This script works great until I download all of my books into the application it gets the books from, and then throws an error. 
The error causes the script to simply shut down, and I need it to keep going, instead of just shut down immediately.

The error is always exactly the same for more than a few books:

```
Traceback "most recent call last" (the quotes here are actually >and<):

File "F:\myfolderwhereitis\obok.py", line 198, in <module> print "%d: %s" "i, volumekeys[key]["title"]" (the quotes from i to [title] are actually >and<)

File "C:\Python27\lib\encodings\cp437.py", line 12, in encode return codecs.charmap_encode "input, errors, ecoding_map" (the quotes from input to encoding_map are actually >and<)

UnicodeEncodingError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character u'\u2026' in position 99: character maps to "undefined" (the quotes around undefinded are actually >and<)
```

I am not a python programmer unfortunately, and I need the books for research on a daily basis, and my laptop is very inconvenient for this purpose.

I would like to know if there is a way to simply either ignore the error (like see it, then skip it and continue on) or fix it so that it makes it work (maybe by putting a generic title, that I can fix later, but like Generic title 1, generic title 2, and so on).

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I doubt anyone is gonna help you with a drm crack here

Comment: You can start [here](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/). Read about `str` vs `unicode` and about exceptions, then you can fix it by yourself.

Comment: Thank you for your replies. The script is not a drm crack for me. It is a kepub to epub converter, which I then have to convert to read in pdf. The book itself is drmfree, but only downloads to the actual software they are using (the author said it is drm free and on amazon it is, but why buy the book twice?).

I cannot figure it out because I had never programmed before. Just found the script and installed what it said to convert the other book, and then this one gives this error.